# How to Junit Test the JsonProcessingException scenario case to be covered

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have service class where in one of the implementation method , ObjectMapper is locally created and the data is written as

```
public class MyService{
public void myMethod(){
try{
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValueAsString(message1);
}catch(JsonProcessingExcepion e){
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Please letme know how to junit test - this JsonProcessingException scenario , tried with Mockito.spy , tried with explicitly throwing JsonProcessingException but in any case this exception is not thrown . Stuck with this, please help with this. Thank you.
}

How to junit test

Answer (score 1):

Try as below.

```
@Mock
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;


@Test
 public void test(){
    doThrow(new  JsonProcessingExcepion()).when(objectMapper).writeValueAsString(anyString ());
//Add your call
}
```

Comment: hi @S. Anushan , i tried with this approach of test() but i couldnt get the jsonprocessingexception raised in junit test class , could you pls help with this any other ways..